# What is the meaning of single underscore as a function in python?

Tags: python, django

I recently started working on python and have seen a lot of _ being used. I understand that _ is used to ignore values 
for e.g.

```
name, _ , shape = get_fruit() # returns a tuple.
```

However, I couldn't get many articles on _ functions e.g.

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

Why is _ used here instead of simply using gettext() ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python

Comment: It's important to understand, `_` is just a normal variable name, like `x` or `foo`. Conventionally, it's reserved for variables that aren't going to be used, as a *signal to the person reading the source code*, but it has no special status in Python.

Comment: It's used for `gettext` to be less obtrusive. It works without interrupting the visual flow of the code.